# How to make a layout in android that sticks to the bottom of the screen until the scrollview is scrolled to a certain position it gets scroll too?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I want to make a android activity screen where a layout is sticked to bottom until scrollview get scroll to a certain position. like in this video samples links:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B14wNBitoI33LWtUNThqcXRIUWc

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B14wNBitoI33QW1BOGR1di1TcGc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

amarjain07's [StickyScrollView](https://github.com/amarjain07/StickyScrollView) maybe a solution you would want to look into. His methodology of assigning the "sticky" views as identified attributes in the layout xml is quite a nifty feature IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) and put the Button-Container inside it.
Pass the container in your_scrollview_activity.xml the following attribute

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1 (reft)" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 2 (right)"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**NOTE:** You need to set a listener in your activity to get the ScrollViews current position / current height. With this *current height* you can calculate the "left space" to the bottom / end of the ScrollView. If your RelativeLayout reaches the bottom or if it's close to the bottom **AND** within the visible area, then call your animation.